# ¿Cómo obtener todas las dependencias de las tablas que usan mis Procedimientos Almacenados?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tsql

Estoy buscando alguna herramienta o método para mapear la relación entre procedimiento almacenado, tablas y columnas. Saber cuales son usadas en select, update, insert o delete.

Encontre que SQL server ya proporciona algo parecido

> **sp_depends** 'dbo.procedure_1'

Pero este no me es útil, ya que muchos de mis procedimientos almacenados usan tablas ubicadas en otras base de datos y esas tablas no las toma en cuenta y la información de `sp_depends` no es muy completa que digamos y algo confusa.

Estoy trabajando con SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Conozco una de pago que tal vez te pueda servir https://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/purchase/product/sqldependencytracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tal caso puedes hacer uso de la consulta siguiente:

```
Select table_name 
from MiOtraBD.information_schema.tables
```

Y con un cursor o bucle while, recorrer la tabla syscomments que en la columna text posee todos los códigos T-SQL de tus objetos programables. Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo como referencia:

```
declare @tabla varchar(50),
        @qry varchar(max)

declare @resultado table(Objeto varchar(50), Tabla varchar(50), Accion varchar(12))


declare crTablas cursor for
select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

open crTablas
fetch next from crTablas into @tabla

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @qry = '
                select  object_name(id) as Objeto, ' + 
                quotename(@tabla, char(39)) + ',
                case
                    when [text] like ''%update ' + @tabla + '%' + '''  then ''Actualiza''
                    when [text] like ''%insert ' + @tabla + '%' + '''   then ''Inserta''
                    when [text] like ''%delete ' + @tabla + '%' + '''    then ''Elimina''
                  else ''Selecciona''
                end as Accion
                from syscomments 
                where [Text] like ''%' + @tabla + '%'' '
    insert into @resultado
    exec(@qry)

    fetch next from crTablas into @tabla
end
select * from @resultado
close crTablas
deallocate crTablas
```

Comment: Muy interesante, lo difícil seria llegar al nivel de las columnas afectadas. Pero muy interesante el método que me explicaste al menos para saber que tablas se les aplica cada acción.

Comment: Mira la tabla information_schema.columns

Answer (score 2):

Deberías usar la función [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql) que está disponible a partir de SQL Server 2008.

---

Por ejemplo:

Siendo, **`DATABASE1`** la base de datos que contiene la tabla:

**TABLA_A**:

```
+----+---------------+
| ID |   DESCRIPTION |
+----+---------------+
```

**`Database2`** la base de datos que contiene la tabla:

**TABLA_B**:

```
+------+-----+
| NAME | QTY |
+------+-----+
```

Y el procedimiento **`USP_DATABASE1_PROC`** creado en **`DATABASE1`**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_DATABASE1_PROC
AS
    SELECT ID
    FROM dbo.TABLA_A;

    UPDATE DATABASE2.dbo.TABLA_B
    SET QTY = 0;
GO
```

Al momento de ejecutar:

```
SELECT ISNULL(referenced_database_name, DB_NAME()) referenced_database_name
   ,referenced_schema_name
   ,referenced_entity_name
   ,referenced_minor_name
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.USP_DATABASE1_PROC', 'OBJECT')
WHERE referenced_minor_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Obtienes:

```
+--------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| referenced_database_name | referenced_schema_name | referenced_entity_name | referenced_minor_name  |
+--------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| DATABASE1                | dbo                    | TABLA_A                | ID                     |
| DATABASE2                | dbo                    | TABLA_B                | QTY                    |
+--------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Donde,

- **referenced_database_name**: Nombre de la base de datos
- **referenced_schema_name**: Esquema a la cual pertenece la tabla
- **referenced_entity_name**: Nombre de la tabla
- **referenced_minor_name**: Columnas afectadas en el procedimiento almacenado

---

**Referencia:**

- [SQL SERVER – Get the List of Object Dependencies](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/)